# Ship Station not posting back to magento

Tags: magento2

I am using the Shistation Module version 2.3.1 on my magento 2.4.3-p1.
There are a few issues I would like to address and need your support in resolving this issue.

1. Shipstation is configured properly in Magento as well as in my shipstation account.
   See https://nimb.ws/q8tUdC
   Still, we are getting errors for configuration on the admin panel. see https://nimb.ws/oa3M6d.
   May I know the reason for this?.
2. All the orders are going from Magento to the shipstation. All orders are downloading and we can see API calls. But nothing is going back to Magento.  None of the updates are going back to Magento.
   On checking log files, we can see only one error as " auctane_api.ERROR: Unique constraint violation found"

Any idea about this issue?

Comment: To fix the admin error message go to: Stores -> Configeration -> Sales -> Shipping Methods -> ShipStation Managed Shipping -> Enabled => No

Comment: This will disable the use of shipstation with magento?

Comment: What are you using ShipStation for (only to process shipments or as a shipping method during checkout and process orders from their backend)?

Comment: Yes..................